# There exists a graph with 8 faces and all vertices of degree 6.

Tags: graph-theory

Textbook problem, confused about the approach.

Comment: What approaches do you have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall the formula $V + F = E + 2$, where $V$ is the number of vertices, $E$ is the number of edges, and $F$ is the number of faces ($8$). Also, recall the Handshake theorem, which tells us the sum of the degrees of vertices is $2E$. That is, $2E = 6V \implies E = 3V$. Thus,
$$V + F = E + 2 = \implies V + 8 = 3V + 2 \implies V = 3.$$
A simple graph on $3$ vertices can have a maximum vertex degree of $2$, not $6$, so we have a contradiction. No such graph exists.